# ASP.Net Core application redirecting to /Account/Login even after implementing IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.2

I have created a simple Identity Server and now trying to authenticate a .Net Core application.
Even after configuring the Startup.cs, when I run the solution, the system is still navigating to /Account/Login;
I am expecting the system to navigate to Identity Server.

Below is my Startup.cs code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "oidc";
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.Name = "identitycookie";
        }).AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44123/identity";
                options.ClientId = "wp7jfcxEHaRE8DUIZka";
                options.ResponseType = "id_token token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
                {
                    AuthorizationEndpoint =
                        "https://localhost:44123/identity/connect/authorize",
                    TokenEndpoint =
                        "https://localhost:44123/identity/connect/token"
                };
            });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Could somebody let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry not very familiar to this topic, upvote so your question could be noticed by some one with wisdom to this field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code :

```
 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
```

Instead of :

```
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "oidc";
```

That will challenge `oidc` scheme and make user redirect to an external authentication provider.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This fixed my issue.

Comment: @Shaam , please accept as answer which may help others who meet same issue .

Comment: Is "oidc" correct?  Should it be OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, which is "OpenIdConnect"?

Comment: @Jess I don't think it matters so long as it's the same as the authentication scheme passed to `.AddOpenIdConnect()`. OP has used `"oidc"` so that is what is in the answer. Personally I use `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to reduce the use of magic strings a prevent typos from causing issues.

Answer (score 2):

[Solution by Nan Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58316188/249742) works well.

An alternative is to set `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ForwardChallenge`. This way, even if *Challenge* is triggered on default "Cookies" scheme, it will be forwarded to "oidc" scheme:

```
.AddCookie(options =>
    {
        // [...]
        options.ForwardChallenge = "oidc";
    })
```